# Spring Batch Excel Reader Workbook NullPointerException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spring-batch, spring-batch-excel

Task is to read excel files in spring batch where the resource path get after the file download from GCS.

> pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

> ExcelReader Method

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<HashMap<String, String>> excelReader() {
    PoiItemReader poiItemReader = new PoiItemReader();
    poiItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(Constants.absolutePath));
    poiItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    poiItemReader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
    return  poiItemReader;
}
```

After downloading from GCS file path is stored in static variable `Constants.absolutePath` file is saving correctly.

But an error is causing like this.

> ErrorTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.poi.PoiItemReader.getNumberOfSheets(PoiItemReader.java:56) ~[spring-batch-excel-0.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.AbstractExcelItemReader.nextSheet(AbstractExcelItemReader.java:178) ~[spring-batch-excel-0.1.1.jar:na]
```

While debugging the `workbook` field is Null.

I have checked with the path is hardcoded without `@StepScope` it works correctly.

I need a solution with dynamically setting the resource for the batch process.

Comment: Is your issue resolved with answer provided by Morten?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the return type of the `excelReader` to `PoiItemReader` worked for me. I think that is because first the file has to be opened, so the method `open(...)`on `ItemStream` needs to be called. If you only provide an `ItemReader` spring does not identify your reader as `ItemStream` and hence there is no call to `open`.

Comment: Changing ItemReader to PoiItemReader resolved my issue. With ItemReader it worked in spring batch 4 but when migration performed ,was getting NPE . With Spring batch 5 needs to make this change. Thanks Morten